# How to limit width of header cell

Tags: css, asp.net, header, width, html-table

[image]

As you can see, I have a table with complex header. I need to prevent horizontal header cell from distorting subheader width when its text is long.

Headers and table are in separate divs. Table is built and filled dynamically.

The difficult part is to make width of cells below remain exactly as I specify in CSS while the top header cell width is limited to the width of cells below.

Top header cells have the following CSS style:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
table-layout: fixed;
display: block;
width: 100%;
```

Asp.net, IE 11, VS 2008

Comment: could you provide a demo to work on?

Answer (score 0):

your comment says that each header cell has 100%.  If you are going to use a percentage, you should divide the 100 by the number of cells and use that as the percentage on each cell.

Comment: <th>Longer<br />Group Header</th> ?

Answer (score 0):

why not just use different divs for the header and the body of the table.. than way you could probably keep all table rows proportional to each other. Something like this.. 
Something like that.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.scrolltable {
  overflow-x: visible;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
.scrolltable > .header {} .scrolltable > .tbody {
  /*noinspection CssInvalidPropertyValue*/
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
}
/* an outside constraint to react against */

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 90%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 140px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transform:translate(25px, 51px) rotate(270deg);
}
td {
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="constrainer">
    <div class="scrolltable">
      <table class="header"> <!-- first div for header -->
        <thead>
          <th>
            header
          </th>
          <th>
           header
          </th>
          <th>
             header
          </th>
          <th>
             header
          </th>
          <th>
            header
          </th>
          <th>
            header
          </th>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <div class="tbody">
        <table><!-- second div for table body /content -->
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                header
              </td>
              <td id="inp01">

              </td>
              <td id="inp02">

              </td>
              <td id="inp03">

              </td>
              <td id="inp04">

              </td>
              <td id="inp05">

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                01
              </td>
              <td id="inp11">

              </td>
              <td id="inp12">

              </td>
              <td id="inp13">

              </td>
              <td id="inp14">

              </td>
              <td id="inp15">

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
               header
              </td>
              <td id="inp21">

              </td>
              <td id="inp22">

              </td>
              <td id="inp23">

              </td>
              <td id="inp24">

              </td>
              <td id="inp25">

              </td>
            </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

   
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I actually do it this way :] Separate headers and separate table body. But it's not so important. In any case, top header line (horizontal) always wider than vertical subheaders. If there are 1 to 3 vertical subheader cells and the top header text is longer, subheaders are stretched, as shown on the picture, while the rest of the table stays normal size, so header gets wider than the table.

Comment: why did you disconnect the headers (which, btw, are missing the <tr>?  If you are not in a hurry, I will try to look at this some more over the weekend.